# Kendo UI for MVC combobox autoclearing user entered text

Tags: telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am working on a page that has a Telerik UI for MVC ComboBox. Currently the ComboBox does not keep user input once the datasource has returned any value from the database. Even if you reload the page, the ComboBox will remember the value from the Datasource and delete any user input once the focus is changed to another input field.

I need the ComboBox to keep user input if they do not select a value from the Datasource populated drop-down. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer on the Kendo UI API reference. If you set the .SyncValueAndText(boolean) to false it will allow custom text to stay in the ComboBox. By default this value is set to true which binds the text and value together.

Here is a link to the API Documentation:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox/configuration/syncvalueandtext